# Slash Command Error: Application did not respond

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Here is my slash command handler file - slash_command_handler.js

```
const { Routes } = require("discord-api-types/v9");
const { Collection } = require('discord.js');
const { Interaction } = require("discord.js");
const fs = require('fs');
module.exports = (client, Discord, REST) => {
    const slash_commands = []
    const slash_commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./Slash Commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
        for(const file of slash_commandFiles){
        const slash_command = require(`../Slash Commands/${file}`);
        slash_commands.push(slash_command.data.toJSON());
        if(slash_command.name){
            client.slash_commands.set(slash_command.name, slash_command);
        } else {
            continue;
        }
    }
    const CLIENT_ID = process.env.CLIENT_ID;
    const GUILD_ID = process.env.GUILD_ID
    const rest = new REST({
        version: "9"
    }).setToken(process.env.DISCORD_TOKEN);
    (async() => {
        try {
            if(process.env.ENV === "production") {
                await rest.put(Routes.applicationCommands(CLIENT_ID),
                { body: slash_commands },
                );
                console.log("Successfully registered commands globally.");
            } else{
                await rest.put(Routes.applicationGuildCommands(CLIENT_ID, GUILD_ID), 
                { body: slash_commands },
                );
                console.log("Successfully registered commands locally.");
            }
        } catch (err){
            if (err) console.error(err);
        }
    })();
};
```

From what has happened, this file (slash_command_handler.js) is working fine. Here is my interactionCreate code which is found in the main file of the bot - index.js

```
client.on("interactionCreate", async interaction => {
    if(interaction.isCommand()) return;
    const command = client.slash_commands.set(interaction.commandName);
    if(!command) return;
    try {
        await command.execute(interaction);
    } catch(err){
        if(err) console.error(err);
        await interaction.reply({
            content: "An error occured while executing that command.",
            ephemeral: true
        });
    }
});
```

I believe it is something to do with `interaction` in the code above that is causing the error. Here is my ping2 test file - ping2.js

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');
module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName("ping2").setDescription("Pong!"),
    async execute(interaction) {
        await interaction.reply({
            content: "Pong!",
            ephemeral: true
        });
    }
}
```

I believe this file above is not this issue and it is the interactionCreate code in index.js. Here is the error message.

```
The application did not respond
```

Please note I can see the slash command when I type `/` to view slash commands, meaning the issue must be when sending or detecting the slash command. When `console.log(interactions)` is used, this is what shows up.

```
CommandInteraction {
  type: 'APPLICATION_COMMAND',
  id: '997220833229541396',
  applicationId: '940659140597010432',
  channelId: '941812808683769917',
  guildId: '909201299613040701',
  user: User {
    id: '905929688189390858',
    bot: false,
    system: false,
    flags: UserFlags { bitfield: 0 },
    username: 'PAdventures',
    discriminator: '1713',
    avatar: '8d0370d025b3f1133fa1c913f1bd2797',
    banner: undefined,
    accentColor: undefined
  },
  member: GuildMember {
    guild: Guild {
      id: '909201299613040701',
      name: 'Pokemonboy Adventures YT',
      icon: 'd0aac2947ed546f4b0d776b0d38eed64',
      features: [Array],
      commands: [GuildApplicationCommandManager],
      members: [GuildMemberManager],
      channels: [GuildChannelManager],
      bans: [GuildBanManager],
      roles: [RoleManager],
      presences: PresenceManager {},
      voiceStates: [VoiceStateManager],
      stageInstances: [StageInstanceManager],
      invites: [GuildInviteManager],
      scheduledEvents: [GuildScheduledEventManager],
      available: true,
      shardId: 0,
      splash: null,
      banner: null,
      description: null,
      verificationLevel: 'VERY_HIGH',
      vanityURLCode: null,
      nsfwLevel: 'DEFAULT',
      premiumSubscriptionCount: 0,
      discoverySplash: null,
      memberCount: 10,
      large: false,
      premiumProgressBarEnabled: true,
      applicationId: null,
      afkTimeout: 300,
      afkChannelId: null,
      systemChannelId: null,
      premiumTier: 'NONE',
      explicitContentFilter: 'ALL_MEMBERS',
      mfaLevel: 'ELEVATED',
      joinedTimestamp: 1657732180813,
      defaultMessageNotifications: 'ALL_MESSAGES',
      systemChannelFlags: [SystemChannelFlags],
      maximumMembers: 500000,
      maximumPresences: null,
      approximateMemberCount: null,
      approximatePresenceCount: null,
      vanityURLUses: null,
      rulesChannelId: '921209936355135508',
      publicUpdatesChannelId: '921879061259755540',
      preferredLocale: 'en-US',
      ownerId: '905929688189390858',
      emojis: [GuildEmojiManager],
      stickers: [GuildStickerManager]
    },
    joinedTimestamp: 1636840882042,
    premiumSinceTimestamp: null,
    nickname: null,
    pending: false,
    communicationDisabledUntilTimestamp: null,
    _roles: [
      '910959267924824064',
      '970015534156488744',
      '967861140656910436',
      '909871820298158181'
    ],
    user: User {
      id: '905929688189390858',
      bot: false,
      system: false,
      flags: [UserFlags],
      username: 'PAdventures',
      discriminator: '1713',
      avatar: '8d0370d025b3f1133fa1c913f1bd2797',
      banner: undefined,
      accentColor: undefined
    },
    avatar: null
  },
  version: 1,
  memberPermissions: Permissions { bitfield: 4398046511103n },
  locale: 'en-GB',
  guildLocale: 'en-US',
  commandId: '997156870244540486',
  commandName: 'ping2',
  deferred: false,
  replied: false,
  ephemeral: null,
  webhook: InteractionWebhook { id: '940659140597010432' },
  options: CommandInteractionOptionResolver {
    _group: null,
    _subcommand: null,
    _hoistedOptions: []
  }
}
```

Comment: I just ran some console.logs and when I do this to commandName, it is undefined. Maybe this is what's causing the bug.

Comment: Typo: `if(interaction.isCommand()) return;` means that if the interaction is a command, the rest of the code will NOT run and for everything else, it will. As only commands have `commandName` property, it will be `undefined`. Change that line to `if(!interaction.isCommand()) return;`

Comment: Thanks, that worked, but now the catch error message: ```An error occured while executing that command.``` showed up. Do you know what I can do to fix this.